# Check constantly for connectivity to a webservice

Tags: vb.net, web-services

Am having a windows service written on vb.net, that every few seconds 10secs or more it will check whether i have a connection to a webservice link, and if i do then ill send some data to that webservice. I wont always have data to send but regardless i want to check if i have connectivity before i try to send anything, and in this case ill know if the service is up or not.
My problem is that after 2-3 tries the connectivity check gives me 'Connection has timed out'.

Here is the code i use:

```
Public Function HaveInternetConnection() As Boolean
        HaveInternetConnection = False
        Try
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(My.Settings.WebServiceLink)
            request.Timeout = 15000

            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse

            If response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
                HaveInternetConnection = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
```

I tried changing the timeout time but no luck.
I Also tried creating a new '`Private ws As New webservice`' on every time interval and not creating 1 new webservice when service starts but again no luck.

Is there any simpler way to check on every few seconds if i have a connection to the webservice?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok, so if you get a timeout error it could be for some other reason.

To just check the connectivity to a host you can ping it, saving you the CPU time to create an `HTTPWebRequest`

Example:

```
If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
    'this only tells that the PC is connected to a network
    'doesn't really mean that there is internet access!
    Try
        My.Computer.Network.Ping("yourhost")
        'here the host has answered the ping request
      Catch ex As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException
        'the ping has failed. your host is unreachable
      End Try
End If
```

Testing if there's a network available saves the CPU from generating an Exception (heavy operation) in case the PC is offline

Comment: i tried pinging the webservice link from cmd and i get error 'Ping request could not find host'.
The link i have starts with "http :// something.something.gr/service/service.asmx"

Comment: Try to specify a port as shown at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he5sca5t(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: this post is not very helpful theBugger. i still get exceptions though 
'An exception occurred during a Ping request.'